# Why isn't there an alter-var-root in clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

There is alter-var-root in clojure. Why there isn't it in cljs?

Answer (score 8):

Clojurescript doesn't have vars. They're just globals you can `set!` like any other object property.